# Passing pointer to pointer for reallocation in function

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, reference, arguments

I'm a beginner C programmer and have issues implementing an (ordered) dynamic array of structs.
Before adding an element to the array, I want to check if it is full and double it's size in that case:

```
void insert_translation(dict_entry **dict, char *word, char *translation){
    if( dictionary_entries == dictionary_size ){
        dict_entry *temp_dict;
        temp_dict = realloc(&dict, (dictionary_size *= 2) * sizeof(dict_entry) );
        // printf("Increased dict size to %d\n", dictionary_size);
        // if(temp_dict == NULL){
        //     fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory during realloc()!\n");
        //     /*free(dict);
        //     exit(EXIT_OUT_OF_MEMORY);*/
        // }

        //free(dict);
        //*dict = temp_dict;
    }

    dictionary_entries++;
    printf("Inserted %s into dict - %d of %d filled.\n", word, dictionary_entries, dictionary_size);
}
```

I call the function from the main function like this:

```
dictionary_size = 2; //number of initial key-value pairs (translations)
dictionary_entries = 0;
dict_entry *dictionary = malloc(dictionary_size * sizeof(dict_entry));
[...]
insert_translation(&dictionary, "bla", "blub");
```

In my understanding, dictionary is a pointer to a space in memory. &dictionary is a pointer to the pointer, which I pass to the function. In the function, dict is said pointer to pointer, so &dict should be the pointer to the area in memory? However, when I try to compile, I get the following error message:

```
pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
```

### Edit

I expanded the code sample to show more of the code in the main function.

Comment: Where is `dictionary_size` declared, initialized?  `dictionary_size *= 2` will not help much when `dictionary_size == 0`

Comment: Most probably (as you are not showing the entire program) you need to do `realloc(*dict, (dictionary_size *= 2) * sizeof(dict_entry) );`

Comment: Two things: In the commented code you do the right thing with `*dict`. And you also do the wrong thing with `free(dict)` (and even `free(*dict)` is wrong).

Comment: "*In the function, dict is said pointer to pointer, so &dict should be the pointer to the area in memory?*" No, `&` is the address-of operator, so `&dict` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to the memory area.

Comment: Thank you everyone - I understand my mistake using the address of operator (&) instead of the dereferencing operator. However, `temp_dict = realloc(*dict, (dictionary_size *= 2) * sizeof(dict_entry) );` still results in the same error message.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you assigning the value returned by `malloc` or `calloc` to `dict` anywhere before you call `realloc`?

Comment: @MemeAccount More babon's point above, after fixing your `&dict` to be `*dict`, note that `*dict` must be either `NULL` or a result of a previous *dynamic* allocation result (from `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`). That need to be a precursor to entering this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this statement

```
temp_dict = realloc(&dict, (dictionary_size *= 2) * sizeof(dict_entry) );
```

The parameter `dict` has the type

```
dict_entry **dict
```

in the statement that reallocs the memory you have to use the value of the pointer `*dic` but you are uisng an expression `&dict` that has the type `dict_entry ***`.

Compare the type of the left side of the assignment

```
ict_entry *temp_dict
```

with the type of the reallocated pointer. They should be the same (except in C one of them can have the type `void *`)

So you need to write

```
temp_dict = realloc(*dict, (dictionary_size *= 2) * sizeof(dict_entry) );
                    ^^^^^
```

In C arguments are passed by value. If you want to change the original value of an argument you should to pass it by reference through a pointer to the argument. In the function you need to dereference the pointer that to change the object pointed to by the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`&dict` -> `*dict`. You can simplify the code by using a return type, to avoid such bugs:

```
dict_entry* insert_translation(dict_entry* dict, char *word, char *translation)
{
  ...

  if( dictionary_entries == dictionary_size )
  {
    dictionary_size *= 2;

    dict_entry *tmp = realloc(dict, sizeof(dict_entry[dictionary_size]));
    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
      // error handling, free(dict) etc
    }
    else
    {
      dict = tmp;
    }
  }

  ...

  return dict;
}
```